# Safest way to run query from client into sql server using Asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new in asp net, i need to ask which is the safest way to run a query from my client into asp net and then into sql server.

First option i am using till now, i create my query from client, example

```
"insert into customers (name) values('john')"
```

And inside asp net i just take my string from client and just excecuted.

```
Inside Post method:
//Here i am getting query from client:
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryFromClient,connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am looking for making my queries more safe, if i will have any injection or hacking into my server, someone can easy send  whatever query he wants, delete database or anything else...
So i am looking a way for prevent this.

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM like EF? It'd be probably easier

Comment: What is Orm? i know how i can handle json, if this helps

Comment: Which database, are stored procedures an option?

Comment: Nice thought! i did't know that i can do that. Yes i can use sql server stored procedures  and passing my paramteres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are receiving the entire query from your client this is unsafe by nature as the client could intercept the request and change the query that they are sending to your Web API to be anything!

To prevent this you should have a statically typed query written out ready to receive parameters from your client, for example, if you have a method in your Web API for inserting a new person into your database, this code would suffice and you would pass the name of the person to the web api.

```
string q = "insert into persons (name) values(@name)"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "james";
```

This method above parameterises your SQL query preventing SQL Injections.

To prevent having to go to such efforts, Microsoft released a framework called [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/) this handles all of this for you and makes your life so much simpler when it comes to building secure web apis quickly.

Comment: The value james will be sent from client but all the entire query will be handled from server side?

Comment: Yes that is correct! you would only send the values to the server not the entire query, that would be highly unsafe

Comment: So instead of sending "insert into persons (name) values('James')", you would simply send the string 'James' and the query would be carried out on the server side.

Comment: Thank you Jame! Also i think the situation to send parameters using json. Is it good practise? Instead just value a "James". Serialize list from client, Deserialize on server and foreach item in list,to create a query for insert

Comment: Yes you've got it, you want to send your parameters as json to the server, and then serialize it into your parameters object on the server and then use the parameters in your SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

There is no safe way at all.
If you take an arbitrary query from the client, it can send literally anything, which gives them full control over the database. Always threat every request parameter as untrusted, potentially dangerous data and never submit directly to the DB.

The safe option is to have the server build all the queries itself, maybe guided by some parameters provided by the client, but the final text should always be composed server-side. Chunks of the query could be conditionally added by the request parameters, and raw data can be parametrized, but everything validated by the server.

That of course means that you won't be able to run arbitrary queries.

Comment: Thank you Alejandro, nice explanation. I need to ask, is it good practice to send a list collection using json, and then in server side creating my standar query and just adding this parameters?

Comment: @user10775950 Yes, that's perfectly safe, as long as you compose the query server-side and add the data as parameters and not by simply concatenating raw values. In fact, that's standard practice, the client submit raw values and the server puts them in the DB using parametrized queries. The problem is sending the whole query and the server blindly running it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SqlCommand.Parameters.Add()` for adding varian\bles:

```
string query = "insert into customers (name) values(@name)"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cms.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "john";
```

Of course for a fixed query without any variables it does not matter that you write it the way it is not or adding parameters, however if you want to add variable values (for example from a textbox), that you will surely do, `cms.Parameters.Add()` is the way to go.

Comment: Imagine that i will send query from a client, and i will run it on asp net server

Comment: well no matter what, it won't be safe, you may choose to encrypt your query, ... but still not a reliable way,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stored Procedure with Parameters

```
Create Procedure USP_INSERTINTOCUSTOMER
@NAME varchar(max)
AS
Begin
   INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (NAME) Values (@Name)
END
```

You can call this in your C# Programs

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_INSERTINTOCUSTOMER",connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "YOUR_VALUE");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```